# Which is an appropriate NodeJS code to send telemetry from device to IoT hub?

Tags: node.js, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, open-telemetry

With the help of Azure IoT SDK node, I've been assigned to send telemetry data from device to IoT hub using NodeJS.
How do I write or how do I find an appropriate sample for d2c messages.
I'm quite confused which sample code to be used from this particular SDK for device to IoT hub telemetry.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node
"Suppose my device has a waste level sensor and sending waste fill level to IoT hub so how do I get an appropriate sample from this SDK to send data to Hub"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest Node SDK sample I could find was [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js)". It's in the repository that you linked to.

If you want more information, and a step-by-step tutorial, I can recommend [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-iot-hub?pivots=programming-language-nodejs&WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) in the docs. It uses a [different sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/device/samples/pnp) in the same repository.

For all of these samples: they send a certain payload. You can change the payload to whatever you need it to be for your waste level sensor!